# "Failed to resolve: com.android.support:support-v4:26.0.0" and other similar errors on Gradle sync

Tags: java, android, gradle, compiler-errors, wear-os

I have just created a new Android Studio project for both Android Mobile *and* wear. The initial gradle build failed because I am getting several errors-

`Error: Failed to resolve: com.android.support:support-v4:26.0.0`

`Error: Failed to resolve: com.android.support:percent:26.0.0`

`Error: Failed to resolve: com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.0.0`

`Error: Failed to resolve: com.android.support:support-annotations:26.0.0`

With each error, I am given the option to `Install repository and sync project`, but nothing happens when I click on it. I have spent several hours trying to find why I am getting these errors, but I can't find any solutions. Does anybody know how to fix these very frustrating errors? Thank you!

**build.gradle (project)**

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they   belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**build.gradle (mobile)**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.1"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.georgeberdovskiy.androidweartest"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-   core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    wearApp project(':wear')
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable:11.0.4'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26+'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile "com.android.support:support-core-utils:26+"
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

**build.gradle (wear)**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.1"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.georgeberdovskiy.androidweartest"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    provided 'com.google.android.wearable:wearable:2.0.4'
    compile 'com.google.android.support:wearable:2.0.4'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable:11.0.4'
    compile "com.android.support:support-core-utils:26+"
}
```

I am sure that my version of Android Studio is updated, and all support repositories and APIs are installed.
[image]

Comment: I am noticing that these errors are only for the wear build.gradle...

Comment: 1) change your buildToolsVersion "26.0.1" into buildToolsVersion "26.0.0" 

2) change dependencies version from  
   compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.0.0'
into 
   compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.0.0-alpha1'

  Hope this helps you.

Comment: changing build version will work, let me know if you find any difficulties on that

Comment: For IONIC 3 check solution here --> https://www.freakyjolly.com/ionic-3-resolve-execution-failed-for-task-appprocessdebugresources/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason that my project was giving me these errors was because I created the project for Android Platform 26. However, Wear currently doesn't support 26, and it is essential to change the `target` and `compile` SDK versions to 25 in the wear module of build.gradle.

Link to Android Developers documentation - https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/apps/creating.html#setting-up-a-phone

**build.gradle (wear)**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'


android {
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion "26.0.1"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.georgeberdovskiy.findmyphone"
    minSdkVersion 25
    targetSdkVersion 25
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),       'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
    }
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.google.android.support:wearable:2.0.3'
provided 'com.google.android.wearable:wearable:2.0.3'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.0.4'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.0.4'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.0.4'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable:11.0.4'

}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

I only needed to change the compile and target SDK versions to 25 in the wear module. I left them as 26 for the mobile module.

Comment: You should make sure to use a buildToolVersion with the same major version number as the compileSdkVersion (in this case 25.X.X) for best result.

Comment: Using build tools 26.0.1 works very well for me. Thank you for the suggestion though.

Answer (score 78):

I don't have an Android wear project, but I had the same problem when I wanted to upgrade the Support Library version for an existing project to 26.0.0. Since 26.0.0 the support libraries are available through Google's Maven repository. So I had to add the repository to my build. gradle file.

```
allprojects {
  repositories {
      jcenter()
      maven {
          url "https://maven.google.com"
      }
  }
}
```

Check out https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/setup.html for more details.

Comment: Wtf. From Maven to JCenter to Maven again...

Answer (score 11):

The following worked for me:

In the Application build.gradle considered to add following:

```
allprojects {
repositories {
    maven {
        url "https://maven.google.com"
    }
}
}
```

in the Module build.gradle:

```
compileSdkVersion 26
buildToolsVersion "26.0.1"

dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable:11.0.4'
compile 'com.android.support:support-compat:26.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.0.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.0.4'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:26.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:26.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:26.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:26.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:26.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:percent:26.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:wear:26.0.1'
compile 'com.google.android.support:wearable:2.0.4'
provided 'com.google.android.wearable:wearable:2.0.4'
}
```

Comment: finally I updated the depencies w IMPLEMETATION instead of COMPILE. I am still not able to split gms:play-services:11.6.2 into single modules, I need. It leads me into a disaster by destroing everything, I am fighting for a fifth night w that, finally giving up and loading the whole package.

Comment: Try com.android.support version should same.

Answer (score 6):

Either change your build tool version from `26.0.1` to `26.0.0` or you can replace `26.0.0` by `26.+` like below.

```
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.0.0'
```

to

```
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.+"
```

Do same with all...
Hope it helps. 
Happy Coding! **^_^**

Comment: Didn't work, still getting the same errors.

Comment: are you on WIFI or Offline? Be sure It needs internet connection.

Comment: Yes, I am connected to WiFi.

Comment: @GeorgeB Either add `'26+1'` in every code or make your build tool version `'26.0.0'` from `'26.0.1'` and sync it. I tested in my work space and it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 3):

Replace this:

```
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.0.0'
```

With this

```
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.0.0-alpha1'
```

**Do same with all**

**Update - new version released**

```
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.1.0'
```

Answer (score 3):

For now, I fixed this with changing in the wear build.gradle:

```
compile 'com.google.android.support:wearable:2.0.3'
provided 'com.google.android.wearable:wearable:2.0.3'
```

It seems like the problem is com.google.android.support:wearable:2.0.4. With that, Using 26.0.1 build tools compiles fine. I haven't gone any further with this but it looks like a dependency problem related to a repository although that is really just a guess from the error messages.

Comment: Thanks @John Smith. It helped for me :)

Answer (score 3):

Add the following dependencies in your `app/build.gradle`.

```
repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    maven{url 'https://maven.google.com'}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Add following dependency in your gradle

Replace

```
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.0.0'
```

with

```
   compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.0.0'
```

and Replace

```
   compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26+'
```

with

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.0'
```

Comment: Didn't work, now I get another error on top of the other ones - `Error:(30, 13) Failed to resolve: com.android.support:support-v4:26.0.0`

Answer (score 1):

This one worked for me

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
}
```

**google()** does the magic with the following configuration

Studio version : **3.0 beta 2**

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0-beta2'

distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.1-rc-1-all.zip
```

Answer (score 0):

I meet this problem, changing the build tool/ sdk version didn't work, clearly write compile version didn't work, off line build didn't work.

Finally I just change wearable version, and this problem gone.

```
provided 'com.google.android.wearable:wearable:2.0.4'
compile 'com.google.android.support:wearable:2.0.4'
```

to

```
provided 'com.google.android.wearable:wearable:2.0.2'
compile 'com.google.android.support:wearable:2.0.2'
```

By the way, I used offline building now because it is really fast when I check this issue.