# Failed to resolve: com.android.support:support-v4:26.0.0 for wear

Tags: android, wear-os

I have installed new Android Studio in Ubuntu, and I keep on getting this error:

[Screen Shot of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sKRDs.png)

Comment: add the missed dependencies to your gradle file, `compile "com.andoid ..."`

Comment: Can you please tell me what after com.android???

Answer (score 1):

Add `compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.0.0'` or `compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.+"` in your gradle then sync it.

Reference: ["Failed to resolve: com.android.support:support-v4:26.0.0" and other similar errors on Gradle sync](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45385199/failed-to-resolve-com-android-supportsupport-v426-0-0-and-other-similar-err)