# Failed to resolve: support-v4?

Tags: android, dependencies

I have following dependencies in build.gradel file.
I am not using any kind of v4 library but ,
still it's giving "Failed to resolve: support-v4" error while i build the gradle.

I have already gone through these 2 links

1. ["Failed to resolve: com.android.support:support-v4:26.0.0" and other similar errors on Gradle sync](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45385199/failed-to-resolve-com-android-supportsupport-v426-0-0-and-other-similar-err)
2. [Failed to resolve: com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33185086/failed-to-resolve-com-android-supportsupport-v423-0-0)

But can't find solution.

Here i have attached project structure image.

[image]

```
android {

compileSdkVersion 26
dataBinding.enabled = true
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "XXX.XXXXXXX.XXXXXXXXXX"
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    multiDexEnabled true
}



dataBinding {
    enabled = true
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
 }

dependencies {
    repositories {
        maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }
    }

implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})


//noinspection GradleCompatible
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
implementation "com.android.support:customtabs:26.1.0"
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint- 
layout:1.0.2'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.+'
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.+'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.2.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.2.1'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'

}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Please help me to get solved this issue.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The `repositories` block goes in your root build.gradle, not your app build.gradle.

Comment: okay will try this one

Comment: @TheWanderer still it gives same issue

Comment: check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/52015145/6401241

Comment: @Radesh thanks for your quick reply it works like charms.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have same problem and i'm change order of `repositories` in biuld.gradle (app) and problem solved.

Change :

```
 jcenter()
 google()
```

To :

```
 google()
 jcenter()
```

Hope it's help

Answer (score 0):

Move repositories in the module `build.gradle` not in app `build.gradle`. It will solve your problem.